# How do we find a good change of coordiantes when solving PDEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Consider the PDE:
$$U_x+2U_y+(2x-y)U=2x^2+3xy-y^2 $$
in my lectures, we have found that using a change of coordiantes of the form:
$$\bar{x}=ax+by,\bar{y}=bx-ay $$
can be useful for solving PDEs. However, we haven't been told how we would pick $a$ or $b$. The intention is for the PDE to boil down to an ODE. Is there a method for selecting $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $a=1$, $b=2$. Then for $V(\bar x, \bar y)=U(x,y)$ one has $U_x=aV_x+bV_y$, $U_y=bV_x-aV_y$, $aU_x+bU_y=(a^2+b^2)V_x$. Note that the subscripts $x,y$ just indicate the position of the argument for the derivative, not the actual contents of the argument.

Comment: @LutzLehmann my question is, how did you know to pick $a=1,b=2$ is there a general method for this?

Comment: This only works for the constant coefficients, if the differential part looks like $aU_x+bU_y$. Otherwise you need to integrate the equations for the characteristic curves.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So you just pick $a$ and $b$ to be the coefficients of the partial derivatives then?

Comment: Yes, that is the construction. The Lagrange equations have $\frac{dx}a=\frac{dy}b$, so that $\bar y=bx-ay$ is constant along the characteristic curves. $\bar x$ only has to be transversal to that, one special choice is the orthogonal $ax+by$.

Comment: @HungaryGoose; Why do you want to change of variable ? The present variables are well convenient to solve the PDE thanks to the method of characteristics.